# Can you implement PayPal Adaptive Payments with the Customer Leaving Your Site?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, payflowpro, chained-payments

Is there any way to implement PayPal Adaptive Payments without the customer ever leaving your site?

The documentation outlines using an embedded lightbox, but unless the user is already logged in to PayPal (which they almost never are), then it just opens a new window. Theres also no way to control how the lightbox / iframe is displayed - and it looks terrible!

I have seen on some sites where the PayPal payments form is embedded in an iframe on a page, but I can't see any documentation supporting that.

I'd be happy to pay for Payments Pro if that would enable it - but I cant find any examples / samples that show using Payments Pro with Adaptive Payments.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: In any case user should authorize any payment (or future payment) at PayPal's website. I believe is not possible to avoid that.

Comment: PayPal payments pro is to accept credit cards, debit cards on your site.  What you do is to gather the card information and sent it using an API call to PayPal. Is that what you want? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/payflow-pro/payflow-pro-integration-paths/

Comment: What I want is to be able to accept payment without leaving my site, and process that payment using a PayPal chained payment. So I'd be happy to accept credit cards as you described, but I cant see how I'd be able to process that using adaptive payments. Equally I'd be happy to use PayPals embedded payment form, but that firstly looks terrible, and secondly always redirects in a new browser window

Comment: I understand more. My opinion is that is not possible, as I stated before, for express check out or adaptive payments the user has to go to PayPal first to authorize the transaction. I also agree that forms look terrible, have you look at PayPal for digital goods?

Answer (score -1):

You can also dynamically select your hosted pages Layout template using the form post TEMPLATE parameter. This will override your default Layout template set in PayPal Manager.

Comment: This isn't an answer at all